# "If I could have paid myself all the money I've paid out in interest over the years": meaning of "in interest"

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

> "Pay your bills and stay hell out of debt. If I could have paid myself
>   all the money I've paid out in interest over the years, I'd be retired
>   already."

What confused me is **"If I could have paid myself all the money I've paid out in interest over the years,I'd be retired already."**

Could anybody help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speaker is talking about the 'amount of money' paid *as interest*.

> [Interest (money)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/interest): *money that is ​charged by a ​bank or other ​financial ​organization for ​borrowing ​money*

The sentence is spoken informally and with little humor. He wants to say that one should stay away from debt. Because he has paid a lot of interest to the finance company/bank. If that amount of money (the interest) is paid him back, he'd do no work and will be retired.